# Launch an AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment with Python 2.7 instead of 3.6

Tags: amazon-web-services, python, elastic-beanstalk

The issue I'm having is pretty straight forward: I used to be able to launch new Elastic Beanstalk environments through the AWS web console for an existing application using a Python 2.7 platform. Now, when launching new environments for an existing application, it only launches them using Python 3.6. The application this is for is written entirely in Python 2.7, so it fails when trying to start instances.

So my question is, how do I get the AWS web console to launch a new Elastic Beanstalk environment using Python 2.7 instead of 3.6? I know you have more control through the AWS EB console, but that doesn't help me in this case, as I'm not easily able to use it.